# Why is my code causing a time limit error, Leetcode 24 ( Linked List)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am working on LeetCode problem [24. Swap Nodes in Pairs](https://leetcode.com/problems/swap-nodes-in-pairs/)
:

> Given a linked list, swap every two adjacent nodes and return its head. You must solve the problem without modifying the values in the list's nodes (i.e., only nodes themselves may be changed.)
>
> #### Example 1
>
> [image]
>
> - **Input:** `head = [1,2,3,4]`
> - **Output:** `[2,1,4,3]`
>
> #### Boilerplate
>
> ```
> # Definition for singly-linked list.
> # class ListNode:
> #     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
> #         self.val = val
> #         self.next = next
> class Solution:
>     def swapPairs(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
> ```

This is my code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def swapPairs(self, head):
        if not head or not head.next:
            return head
        slow = head
        fast = head.next
        temp = ListNode(0)
        runner = temp
        while fast:
            runner.next = fast
            runner.next.next = slow
            slow = fast.next
            fast = slow.next
            if not slow:
                return temp.next
            if not fast.next:
                runner = runner.next.next.next
                runner = fast
                runner.next = slow
                return temp.next
```

#### Problem

On LeetCode my code is causing a time limit error. Yet I drew out my code and I expected it to work...

Can someone please explain why I am running into this issue, and whether the issue is that my code isn't optimized or it is just incorrect?

Comment: After the first time you do `runner.next.next = slow` you end up with a `runner->fast->slow->fast->slow->...` list with a cycle that never again changes, leading to an infinite loop. I haven't gone to Leetcode to see what problem you were trying to solve (you should describe it briefly, in the question), but there's clearly some kind of logic error in your algorithm. You're loosing your reference to all of the list after the initial `fast` node!

Answer (score 2):

Your code will create an infinite loop once it has entered the loop (which will happen when the list has at least two nodes).

Let's see what happens with a list with just two nodes, which we can picture as:

```
 head
   │
┌──┴─────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │
│ next: ─────────┤ next: None │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

Then your function will add a dummy node and some local names, which we can picture as follows:

```
 head   slow             fast
   │     │                │
┌──┴─────┴───┐   ┌────────┴───┐
│ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │
│ next: ─────────┤ next: None │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘
         
 runner  
   │     
┌──┴─────────┐
│ val: 0     │
│ next: None │
└──┬─────────┘
   │
 temp
```

So far, so good. Then the loop starts its first iteration. After `runner.next = fast` and `runner.next.next = slow` we get this situation:

```
 head   slow             fast
   │     │                │
┌──┴─────┴───┐   ┌────────┴───┐
│ val: 1     │   │ val: 2     │
│ next: ─────────┤ next: ┐    │
└──────────┬─┘   └───────│──┬─┘
           └─────────────┘  │
 runner                     │
   │                        │
┌──┴─────────┐              │
│ val: 0     │              │
│ next: ────────────────────┘
└──┬─────────┘
   │
 temp
```

This effectively makes the second node the first, and makes the first node follow after the second. But something you overlooked is that now you have lost the original reference of `fast.next`, as this has now been overwritten. So the next `slow = fast.next` is not doing what you intended, because this `fast.next` is no longer the node that originally followed it, but `slow` itself, so this assignment is without consequence. Also `fast = slow.next` accomplishes nothing. And the `if` conditions that follow are never going to be true either.

So we have now a list with a cycle (there is no node with its `next` attribute equal to `None`), and the loop will keep looking at the same state over and over again as `slow` and `fast` keep referencing the same nodes.

In summary: the problem is that you lose the reference to the original successor of `fast`.

You could save that reference to a `nextslow` name to indicate that in the next iteration that node will take the role of `slow`.

Using your naming conventions, you can have this correction:

```
class Solution(object):
    def swapPairs(self, head):
        slow = head
        temp = ListNode(0)
        runner = temp
        while slow and slow.next:
            fast = slow.next
            nextslow = fast.next
            runner.next = fast
            fast.next = slow
            runner = slow
            slow = nextslow
        runner.next = slow
        return temp.next
```

You could also avoid the extra name, and use tuple assignment:

```
class Solution(object):
    def swapPairs(self, head):
        slow = head
        temp = ListNode(0)
        runner = temp
        while slow and slow.next:
            fast = slow.next
            runner.next, fast.next, runner, slow = fast, slow, slow, fast.next
        runner.next = slow
        return temp.next
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely creating a circular loop in the linked list (you need to test more cases).  Also, the fast/slow approach is typically used to split a linked list in two and it makes your code overly complex.  For pair swapping, you'd be better with an even/odd concept.

For example:

```
def swapPairs(self, head):
    if not head: return head
    even, odd  = head, head.next               # first pair
    head, tail = odd, None                     # new head
    while even and odd:
        even.next, odd.next = odd.next, even   # swap pair's links
        if tail: tail.next = odd               # previous --> swapped pair
        tail = even                            # advance previous
        even = even.next                       # advance to next pair
        odd  = even.next if even else None        
    return head
```